# Generating script when using EclipseLink

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink as JPA implementation and I am adding these properties in the *persistence.xm*l but I can't see any scripts generated? Where are they supposed to be saved or have I misunderstood this property.

```xml
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both" />
```

Is it possible to define a script as well that would be run after the tables are created? The same way as a seed script in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink should use "createDDL.jdbc" and place it in the current working directory by default.  You can change this by specifying the "eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" property for the file name and "eclipselink.application-location" to change the location.